# completely testing an algorithm output (dynamic programming longest subsequence)

Tags: java, algorithm, dynamic-programming

Before i start i just want to say this is for a homework assignment.  An issue i have faced recently in this class is the ability to test my code effectively so that when i submit my solutions i can be confident all input combinations will be covered.  I have been told that much of testing is subjective and requires actual knowledge of the implementation.. one size never fits all.  That being said are there guidelines on how to effectively test?

One example i am currently struggling with is dynamic programing implementation of longest subsequence if elements.  All of my tests work but when i submit to the grader i get stuck at what i assume is an edgecase ( we are not allowed to see the input or output of a failed test case after a certain test ).

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class LCS2 {
    int [][] solutionMatrix;
    public int lcs2(int[] a, int[] b) {
        final int aARRAY_LENGTH = a.length + 1;
        final int bARRAY_LENGTH = b.length + 1;
        solutionMatrix = new int[aARRAY_LENGTH][bARRAY_LENGTH];


    //set endge indexes equal to i
    for (int i = 1; i < aARRAY_LENGTH; i++) {
        solutionMatrix[i][0] = i;
    }
    for (int i = 1; i < bARRAY_LENGTH; i++) {
        solutionMatrix[0][i] = i;
    }
    //fill in matrix to determine if each element is a insert, delete, match or mismatch
    for (int i = 1; i < aARRAY_LENGTH; i++) {
        for (int j = 1; j < bARRAY_LENGTH; j++) {
            int insertion = solutionMatrix[i    ][j - 1] + 1;
            int deletion  = solutionMatrix[i - 1][j    ] + 1;
            int match     = solutionMatrix[i - 1][j - 1];
            int mismatch  = solutionMatrix[i - 1][j - 1] + 1;
            //System.out.println("i: " + i + " j: " + j + " [" +insertion + " " + deletion + " " + match + " " + mismatch + "] ");
            if (a[i - 1] == b[j - 1])
                solutionMatrix[i][j] = Math.min(insertion, Math.min(deletion,match));
            else
                solutionMatrix[i][j] = Math.min(insertion, Math.min(deletion,mismatch));
        }
    }
    //print out matrix for visualization
    System.out.println("       " + Arrays.toString(b));
    for (int i = 0; i < aARRAY_LENGTH; i++) {
      if (i - 1 < 0)
        System.out.println("    " + Arrays.toString(solutionMatrix[i]));
      else
        System.out.println("[" + a[i -1] + "] " + Arrays.toString(solutionMatrix[i]));
    }
    return outputAlignment(a.length, b.length, 0);
}
private int outputAlignment(int i, int j, int ret){
    //recursive call..  if indexes are 0 then return
    if (i == 0 && j == 0)
        return ret;
    //find pointer.. is this a insert, deletion, match or mismatch
    int backtrack = backtrack(i, j);
    //change current index based on result of backtrack
    if (backtrack == 3)
    //if matched then add one to the longest sequence
        ret = outputAlignment(i - 1, j - 1, ret) + 1;
    else if (backtrack == 2)
        ret = outputAlignment(i - 1, j    , ret);
    else if (backtrack == 1)
        ret = outputAlignment(i    , j - 1, ret);
    else
        ret = outputAlignment(i - 1, j - 1, ret);

    return ret;
}
private int backtrack(int i, int j){
    //System.out.println("i: " + i + " j: " + j);
    int currValue = solutionMatrix[i][j];
   // System.out.println(currValue);
    if (     currValue == solutionMatrix[i    ][j - 1] + 1)
        return 1; // insertion
    else if (currValue == solutionMatrix[i - 1][j    ] + 1)
        return 2; //deletion
    else if (currValue == solutionMatrix[i - 1][j - 1]    )
        return 3; //match
    else if (currValue == solutionMatrix[i - 1][j - 1] + 1)
        return 4; //mismatch
    return 5;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    int n = scanner.nextInt();
    int[] a = new int[n];
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        a[i] = scanner.nextInt();
    }

    int m = scanner.nextInt();
    int[] b = new int[m];
    for (int i = 0; i < m; i++) {
        b[i] = scanner.nextInt();
    }
    LCS2 lcs = new LCS2();
    System.out.println(lcs.lcs2(a, b));
}
}
```

Here are some junit tests i have put together with no additional setup needed to run.

```
  @Test
public void testLCS2(){
    LCS2 lcs = new LCS2();
    int[] a = {2,7,5};
    int[] b = {2,5};
    assertEquals("Testing Longest Common SubSequence for [2,7,5] --> [2,5]", 2,lcs.lcs2(a,b));

    a = new int[] {2,3,9};
    b = new int[] {2,9,7,8};
    assertEquals("Testing Longest Common SubSequence for [2,3,9] --> [2,9,7,8]", 2,lcs.lcs2(a,b));

    a = new int[] {1,2,3,4};
    b = new int[] {1,2,3,4};
    assertEquals("Testing Longest Common SubSequence for [1,2,3,4] --> [1,2,3,4]", 4,lcs.lcs2(a,b));

    a = new int[] {7};
    b = new int[] {1,2,3,4};
    assertEquals("Testing Longest Common SubSequence for [7] --> [1,2,3,4]", 0,lcs.lcs2(a,b));

    a = new int[] {2,7,8,3};
    b = new int[] {5,2,8,7};
    assertEquals("Testing Longest Common SubSequence for [2,7,8,3] --> [5,2,8,7]", 2,lcs.lcs2(a,b));

    a = new int[] {1,1,1,1};
    b = new int[] {1,2,3,4};
    assertEquals("Testing Longest Common SubSequence for [2,7,8,3] --> [5,2,8,7]", 1,lcs.lcs2(a,b));

    a = new int[] {1,1,1,1};
    b = new int[] {1,2,3,4,1};
    assertEquals("Testing Longest Common SubSequence for [2,7,8,3] --> [5,2,8,7]", 2,lcs.lcs2(a,b));
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by _we are not allowed to see the input or output of a failed test case_?  Talk to the prof if the grader won't provide useful feedback to help you learn.

Comment: yeah the point is that we do not see the output of the grader.. it is meant to make us "think" and debug ourselves.

Comment: I _think_ the grader is being an ass.  In the real world the first thing you do is get the input which caused the error so you can recreate the error so it can be debugged.  Talk to the prof.

Comment: make a function that randomly generates small subsequences, and make a brute force solver and test your solution against the brute force solver. If it gives you the right answer, then it's highly likely that your solution is correct. Now think of errors for larger sequences -> Running out of memory, integer overflow, stack over flow from too much recursion, timeouts etc. Make some extra large sequences to test it on until it blows up. Have fun.

Answer (score 1):

Before posting here, you should have done your research to answer your stated question: "are there guidelines on how to effectively test?"  It's easy enough to find overviews on mind-numbing length, such as [this](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/software_testing/software_testing_quick_guide.htm) very good one.

In your case, I suggest outlining "equivalence classes".  Since exhaustive testing is impractical in most cases, and impossible when the input is of arbitrary length, you develop representative cases -- one for each class, to stand for all members of that class.  For instance, lists with no common members might form one such class.

I can't comment well on your given tests, in part because you haven't explained *why* you tested these particular inputs, or *why* you decided that these were sufficient.  Equivalence classes require you to analyze the problem to determine (or estimate) what processing differences there might be among various inputs.

Write out your rationale, and perhaps get a friend to brainstorm with you.  Have you covered various ways in which the first iterations of your algorithm could go down the wrong path, and have to backtrack?

Answer (score 0):

So in conjunction with all of your responses i ended up doing the following so thank you for your help.

1. bruce force algorithm to compare to
2. found the bug in my underlying algorithm
3. simplified the whole thing with only one method called from main or junit

   ```
   int [][] solutionMatrix;
   public int lcs2(int[] a, int[] b) {
     final int aARRAY_LENGTH = a.length + 1;
     final int bARRAY_LENGTH = b.length + 1;
     solutionMatrix = new int[aARRAY_LENGTH][bARRAY_LENGTH];


     //fill in matrix to determine if each element is a insert, delete, match or mismatch

     for (int i=0; i<=a.length; i++) {
         for (int j=0; j<=b.length; j++) {
             if (i == 0 || j == 0)
                 solutionMatrix[i][j] = 0;
             else if (a[i-1] == b[j-1])
                 solutionMatrix[i][j] = solutionMatrix[i-1][j-1] + 1;
             else
                 solutionMatrix[i][j] = Math.max(solutionMatrix[i-1][j], solutionMatrix[i][j-1]);
         }
     }

     return solutionMatrix[a.length][b.length];
   ```

   }